# Encryption at rest - best practice for Mongodb Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I'm building a SaaS solution in 2023, using MongoDb and Atlas (MERN stack) and want to ensure that the application is secure.

Is there a best practice on how to encrypt data at rest? Whilst data still remaining possible to query?

Comment: [Encryption at Rest](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-kms-encryption/): "*Atlas encrypts all cluster storage and snapshot volumes at rest by default.*"

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe it's me not understanding the basics, but how is this possible when I can see every single word in the database when browsing through my Atlas database? Does this encryption not mean that it should be encrypted also when viewing?

Comment: No, it is encrypted on disc. If a bad guy is able to get a copy of the data folder, then he cannot use it. For the application it is transparent. The encryption key is visible only for the mongod user.